# Sorting two log data arrays in relation to time in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to create a new matrix based of off two data-frames. The first array, df1 collects data each second and the second array df2 in 30 minute intervals. Ideally the data from df2 would be added to df1 to represent the correct time series. The data is completely irregular in practice and comes in randomly based if certain sensors are activated. The examples matrices are:

```
df1 = [['10-11', '14:21:01', '65'],
       ['10-11', '14:21:02', '55'],
       ['10-11', '14:21:03', '26'],
       ['12-11', '17:29:58', '89'],
       ['12-11', '17:29:59', '12'],
       ['12-11', '17:30:00', '65'],
       ['12-11', '17:30:01', '3'],
       ['12-11', '17:30:02', '66'],
       ['12-11', '17:30:03', '971']]

df2 = [['10-11', '14:30', '9.9','112'],
       ['10-11', '15:00', '7.8','165'],
       ['12-11', '17:00', '6.1','154'],
       ['12-11', '17:30', '6.2','165'],
       ['12-11', '18:00', '6.5','170']]
```

I would like to sort the data in a way that, for example the rows with data between 14:00:00 - 14:29:59 in df1 would have the values for the '9.9','112' added to each row, which corresponds to the relevant value in df2. The idea would be that the resulting data frame would appear something like the array below:

```
finaldf = [['10-11', '14:21:01', '65', '9.9','112'],
           ['10-11', '14:21:02', '55', '9.9','112'],
           ['10-11', '14:21:03', '26', '9.9','112'],
           ['12-11', '17:29:58', '89', '6.2','165'],
           ['12-11', '17:29:59', '12', '6.2','165'],
           ['12-11', '17:30:00', '65', '6.5','170'],
           ['12-11', '17:30:01', '3', '6.5','170'],
           ['12-11', '17:30:02', '66', '6.5','170'],
           ['12-11', '17:30:03', '971', '6.5','170']]
```

I'm sorry if this comes across as convoluted and any help solving this or pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pd.merge_asof` after creating datetime indexes:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)

df_1 = df_1.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df_1[0]+' ' +df_1[1],format='%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
df_2 = df_2.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df_2[0]+ ' ' +df_2[1],format='%m-%d %H:%M'))

arr_out = pd.merge_asof(df_1, df_2, 
                        right_index=True, left_index=True, 
                        direction='forward', suffixes=('','_r'))\
            .drop(['0_r','1_r'], 1).values.tolist()

arr_out
```

Output:

```
[['10-11', '14:21:01', '65', '9.9', '112'],
 ['10-11', '14:21:02', '55', '9.9', '112'],
 ['10-11', '14:21:03', '26', '9.9', '112'],
 ['12-11', '17:29:58', '89', '6.2', '165'],
 ['12-11', '17:29:59', '12', '6.2', '165'],
 ['12-11', '17:30:00', '65', '6.2', '165'],
 ['12-11', '17:30:01', '3', '6.5', '170'],
 ['12-11', '17:30:02', '66', '6.5', '170'],
 ['12-11', '17:30:03', '971', '6.5', '170']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create new columns in `df1` and populate them by iterating over the rows (can be *very* slow for large DataFrames) in `df2` and filtering the times using `datetime`. From your example

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df1 = [['10-11', '14:21:01', '65'],
       ['10-11', '14:21:02', '55'],
       ['10-11', '14:21:03', '26'],
       ['12-11', '17:29:58', '89'],
       ['12-11', '17:29:59', '12'],
       ['12-11', '17:30:00', '65'],
       ['12-11', '17:30:01', '3'],
       ['12-11', '17:30:02', '66'],
       ['12-11', '17:30:03', '971']]

df2 = [['10-11', '14:30', '9.9','112'],
       ['10-11', '15:00', '7.8','165'],
       ['12-11', '17:00', '6.1','154'],
       ['12-11', '17:30', '6.2','165'],
       ['12-11', '18:00', '6.5','170']]

# convert to pandas DataFrame and name columns
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1, columns=['date', 'time', 'val1'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2, columns=['date', 'time', 'val2', 'val3'])

finaldf = df1
finaldf['val2'] = -1  # initialize to -1
finaldf['val3'] = -1  # initialize to -1
for i, d, t, v2, v3 in df2.itertuples():
    # get the starting time by subtracting 30 minutes
    tmin = (dt.datetime.strptime(t, '%H:%M') + dt.timedelta(minutes=-30)).time().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    tmax = t + ":00"  # add seconds to end of string

    # filter df1 by matching date and time range
    index = (finaldf['date'] == d) & (finaldf['time'] >= tmin) & (finaldf['time'] < tmax)
    finaldf.loc[index, 'val2'] = v2
    finaldf.loc[index, 'val3'] = v3
```

Output

```
print finaldf

    date      time val1 val2 val3
0  10-11  14:21:01   65  9.9  112
1  10-11  14:21:02   55  9.9  112
2  10-11  14:21:03   26  9.9  112
3  12-11  17:29:58   89  6.2  165
4  12-11  17:29:59   12  6.2  165
5  12-11  17:30:00   65  6.5  170
6  12-11  17:30:01    3  6.5  170
7  12-11  17:30:02   66  6.5  170
8  12-11  17:30:03  971  6.5  170
```

Note that in this code, I am converting the time string into a `datetime` and calling the `time()` function to just get the time. A better way *may* be to convert the whole date and time into a `datetime.datetime` and applying the `timedelta` to the whole thing. (I couldn't infer from your data if it was MM-DD or DD-MM.)